# Bash arithmetic expression's side effects not executed

Tags: bash, post-increment, arithmetic-expressions, side-effects

```
$ declare -i i=0
$ for j in {0..2}; do echo "${j} $((i++))"; done
0 0
1 1
2 2
$ for j in {0..2}; do echo "$(echo "${j} $((i++))")"; done
0 3
1 3
2 3
$
```

Why `i` doesn't get incremented in the 2nd for loop?

(Yes, I know that there's a workaround.)

Comment: You are doing the work in a sub-shell.

Comment: `$(subshell with its own environment)` vs `$((arithmetic expression))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gets incremented in the subshell created by the `$(command substitution)`. When that process exits, the modified value is lost.

Here are similar ways of seeing the same effect:

```
i=0

bash -c 'let i++'    # Subprocess
( let i++  )         # Explicit subshell
let i++ & wait       # Backgrounded process
: <( let i++ )       # Process substitution
let i++ | cat        # Pipeline

echo "$i"            #  Still 0
```